# How to upper all columns from DataFrame except columns from list if columns from list exists in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, uppercase

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below (my real DF has many many more columns):

**Input data:**

```
COL1  | col2   | col3
------|--------|-------
 X    | 11     | 2021
 Y    | 22     | 1990
```

**Requirements:**

And I need to make upper each column names in DataFrame except column names from list below if columns from list exists:

```
list_not_to_up = ["col2", "col55"]
```

my code is:

```
df.columns = [x.upper() if x not in df[list_not_to_up].columns else x for x in df.columns]
```

Nevertheless I have error: `KeyError: "['col55'] not in index"`

**Desire output:**

```
COL1  | col2   | COL3
------|--------|-------
 X    | 11     | 2021
 Y    | 22     | 1990
```

How to modify my code so as to upper all columns from DataFrame except columns from list if of course columns from list exists in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Comment: I know, but is it possible to modify some code so as ignore that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) on the column [`difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
df.rename(columns={c: c.upper() for c in df.columns.difference(list_not_to_up)})
```

Output:

```
  COL1  col2  COL3
0    X    11  2021
1    Y    22  1990
```